# For every positive integer $a$, find a composite number $n$ such that $n|a^n -a$.

Tags: exponentiation

For every positive integer $a$, find a composite number $n$ such that $n|a^n -a$.

Solution:

We have

$ a^n - a$

$ = a[a^{(n-1)}-1]$

If a=n, then $n|a^n -a$

Is this the way to do it or do I need to do it in another way?

Comment: Since your suggestion is to use $n=a$ and the task is finding a composite number $n$, the obvious question would be what to do if $a=1$ or $a$ is a prime.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Seems like I am stuck. Can you please help.

Comment: If $n$ is a Carmichael number and $\gcd(a,n)=1$ , then we have $a^n\equiv a\mod n$. So, we only have to find a Carmichael number $n$ coprime to $a$, this should be possible no matter what $a$ is. I am however not sure how to prove that. If there are infinite many positive integers $k$ such that $6k+1,12k+1,18k+1$ are all prime , we are done, unfortunately this is not known.

Answer (score 4):

You're done when $a$ is composite itself. When $a=1$, just pick any composite $n$. When $a$ is an odd prime, let $n=2a$, then clearly $a^n-a$ is even i.e. $2\mid a^n-a$, and obviously $a\mid a^n-a$, as $\gcd(2,a)=1$, we have $2a\mid a^n-a$.

$a=2$ is tricky. I did a computer search, and $n = 341 = 11 \cdot 31$ is the minimal solution.

As commented below, this is the smallest Fermat psuedoprime to base $2$. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime#Properties) mentioned a method to construct them by Cipolla, with $341$ given as an example.

Comment: Yep. You just re-discovered the smallest Fermat pseudoprime to base $2$.